# Single colon in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm confused with the syntax "single colon" in OCaml.
Snippet:

```
let update_variable (old_state : state) (var_name : var) (new_value : value) : var -> value option =
  fun x -> if x = var_name then Some new_value else old_state x
```

The type inference of this function is state->var->value->value option. I'm confused with the colon before the var->value option. What does it mean? Is an additional parameter omitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colon in OCaml is used to indicate typing. Usually, when you see something like `ident : type`, it means you're indicating `ident` has type `type`. For instance, you could do something

```ml
let a : int = 3
```

This also extends to function definition; however, in this case, since there are many identifiers before the `=`, it may confuse you about which identifier is being typed. Well, it's actually the whole thing before that is typed, the idea being that it will match what you have in your code. For instance, if you have something like

```ml
let f (x : 'a) : 'b =
  ...
```

it means `f : 'a -> 'b`. You could understand it as

```ml
let (f (x : 'a)) : 'b =
  ...
```

even though this is not valid syntax. This is because when, in your code, you will see something like `f x`, you'll know it will have type `'b`.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that explicit typing is rarely used in OCaml. In this case it is being used to give `update_variable` a more specific type than would otherwise be *inferred*.

Consider a simple, contrived example:

```
utop # 
type foo = Foo
let f a b = a = b
let g (a : foo) (b : foo) = a = b;;
type foo = Foo
val f : 'a -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
val g : foo -> foo -> bool = <fun>
```

Without explicit type hints, in function `f` there is nothing know about parameters `a` and `b` except that they must be the same type.

We'd get the same behavior in `g` except that we've explicitly told it `a` and `b` must be of type `foo`. We can achieve the same by only specifying the type of *one* of the two parameters.

```
utop # 
let h (a : foo) b = a = b;;
val h : foo -> foo -> bool = <fun>
```